# Python: replace string, matched from a list

Tags: python, replace

Trying to match and mark character based n-grams. The string

```
txt = "how does this work"
```

is to be matched with n-grams from the list

```
ngrams = ["ow ", "his", "s w"]
```

and marked with `<>` – however, only if there is no preceding opened quote. The output i am seeking for this string is `h<ow >does t<his w>ork` (notice the double match in the 2<sup>-nd</sup> part, but within just 1 pair of expected quotes).

The for loop i’ve tried for this doesn’t, however, produce the wanted output at all:

```
switch = False

for i in txt:
    if i in "".join(ngrams) and switch == False:
        txt = txt.replace(i, "<" + i)
        switch = True
    if i not in "".join(ngrams) and switch == True:
        txt = txt.replace(i, ">" + i)
        switch = False

print(txt)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does it produce instead ?

Comment: What should happen if you have `ngrams = ['his', 's wo', 'wor']`. Do you expect to get `how does t<his wor>k`?

Comment: How to handle multiple matches? E.g. `ngrams = ['ab']`, `txt = 'abominable abs'`. Do you expect `<ab>ominable abs`, `<ab>ominable <ab>s` or `abominable <ab>s`?

Comment: How to handle `ngram` element that is not present in `txt`?

Comment: [@ Mad Physicist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129464/python-replace-string-matched-from-a-list#comment81230479_47129464), 1) aye – 2) # II – 3) in no way; the list is actually a filter for the string, changing only string parts present in both

Comment: Ok. You can do this using list comprehensions and itertools. I'll draft a thing in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses the `str.find` method to find all copies of an ngram within the `txt` string, saving the indices of each copy to the `indices` set so we can easily handle overlapping matches.

We then copy `txt`, char by char to the `result` list, inserting angle brackets where required. This strategy is more efficient than inserting the angle brackets using multiple `.replace` call because each `.replace` call needs to rebuild the whole string.

I've extended your data slightly to illustrate that my code handles multiple copies of an ngram.

```
txt = "how does this work now chisolm"
ngrams = ["ow ", "his", "s w"]
print(txt)
print(ngrams)

# Search for all copies of each ngram in txt
# saving the indices where the ngrams occur
indices = set()
for s in ngrams:
    slen = len(s)
    lo = 0
    while True:
        i = txt.find(s, lo)
        if i == -1:
            break
        lo = i + slen 
        print(s, i)
        indices.update(range(i, lo-1))

print(indices)

# Copy the txt to result, inserting angle brackets
# to show matches
switch = True
result = []
for i, u in enumerate(txt):
    if switch:
        if i in indices:
            result.append('<')
            switch = False
        result.append(u)
    else:
        result.append(u)
        if i not in indices:
            result.append('>')
            switch = True

print(''.join(result))
```

**output**

```
how does this work now chisolm
['ow ', 'his', 's w']
ow  1
ow  20
his 10
his 24
s w 12
{1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 24, 25}
h<ow >does t<his w>ork n<ow >c<his>olm
```

---

If you want adjacent groups to be merged, we can easily do that using the `str.replace` method. But to make that work properly we need to pre-process the original data, converting all runs of whitespace to single spaces. A simple way to do that is to split the data and re-join it.

```
txt = "how  does this\nwork  now chisolm hisow"
ngrams = ["ow", "his", "work"]

#Convert all whitespace to single spaces
txt = ' '.join(txt.split())

print(txt)
print(ngrams)

# Search for all copies of each ngram in txt
# saving the indices where the ngrams occur
indices = set()
for s in ngrams:
    slen = len(s)
    lo = 0
    while True:
        i = txt.find(s, lo)
        if i == -1:
            break
        lo = i + slen 
        print(s, i)
        indices.update(range(i, lo-1))

print(indices)

# Copy the txt to result, inserting angle brackets
# to show matches
switch = True
result = []
for i, u in enumerate(txt):
    if switch:
        if i in indices:
            result.append('<')
            switch = False
        result.append(u)
    else:
        result.append(u)
        if i not in indices:
            result.append('>')
            switch = True

# Convert the list to a single string
output = ''.join(result)

# Merge adjacent groups
output = output.replace('> <', ' ').replace('><', '')
print(output)
```

**output**

```
how does this work now chisolm hisow
['ow', 'his', 'work']
ow 1
ow 20
ow 34
his 10
his 24
his 31
work 14
{32, 1, 34, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 20, 24, 25, 31}
h<ow> does t<his work> n<ow> c<his>olm <hisow>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. If `ngrams` don’t have spaces, for instance `ngrams = ["ow", "his", "work"]`, currently this produces `h<ow> does t<his> <work> n<ow> c<his>olm`. Could this be modified to ignore spaces and combine enclosed words if space (or linebreak) is separating them, like `h<ow> does t<his work> n<ow> c<his>olm`?

Comment: Outstanding, this post-processing approach works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
txt = "how does this work"
ngrams = ["ow ", "his", "s w"]

# first find where letters match ngrams
L = len(txt)
match = [False]*L
for ng in ngrams:
    l = len(ng)
    for i in range(L-l):
        if txt[i:i+l] == ng:
            for j in range(l):
                match[i+j] = True

# then sandwich matches with quotes 
out = []
switch = False
for i in range(L):
    if not switch and match[i]:
        out.append('<')
        switch = True
    if switch and not match[i]:
        out.append('>')
        switch = False
    out.append(txt[i])
print "".join(out)
```

Comment: output is `h<ow d>oes t<his wo>rk` and OP wants `h<ow >does t<his w>ork`

Comment: @SandeepLade ok fixed it

Comment: Man, this looks terrifying – 3 if clauses and 4 for loops to surround my matches with quotes... And i was expecting this part of the project to be the easier one. Thank you, i will check it out tomorrow. Will try to comprehend this.

Comment: Note that using higher level functions like `replace` hide away loops that are still happening under the hood... And this is just "a" solution that works, by no mean have I spent any effort to find "the best" solution...

Comment: I guess that’s what Python usually does overall. Would you mind adding a version with `replace`?

Comment: I don't have any in mind. (But I'm not an expert in string manipulation, I'm sure someone used to it can come up with a clever and cryptic regex that will do the job too.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method with only one for loop. I timed it and it's about as fast as the other answers to this question. I think it's a bit more clear, although that might be because I wrote it.

I iterate over the index of the first character in the n-gram, then if it matches, I use a bunch of if-else clauses to see whether I should add a `<` or `>` in this situation. I add to the end of the string `output` from the original `txt`, so I'm not really inserting in the middle of a string.

```
txt = "how does this work"
ngrams = set(["ow ", "his", "s w"])
n = 3
prev = -n
output = ''
shift = 0
open = False
for i in xrange(len(txt) - n + 1):
    ngram = txt[i:i + n]
    if ngram in ngrams:
        if i - prev > n:
            if open:
                output += txt[prev:prev + n] + '>' + txt[prev + n:i] + '<'
            elif not open:
                if prev > 0:
                    output += txt[prev + n:i] + '<'
                else:
                    output += txt[:i] + '<'
                open = True
        else:
            output += txt[prev:i]
        prev = i
if open:
    output += txt[prev:prev + n] + '>' + txt[prev + n:]
print output
```